# Creating a tag cloud using MVC 3, VBNET, and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, tag-cloud

I am creating a tag cloud and have read the various posts that describe creating tag clound in mvc including the one at mikesdotnetting, wijix.com, and codevoyeur. I also read the posts at SO on the matter. However i am having a block(mentally) as to how to handle the insert of the tags. I can insert the tags as a comma delimited string into my Posts table without issue. However I also need to insert each individual word into my Tags table. I need to sp[lit the tag string into individual words and then insert the individual words into my TagTable. I know how to handle the split but how can i handle the insert of separate tag words into the Tag table when i insert the post at the same time?

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, the issue you are trying to deal with doesn't pertain to creating a tag cloud so much as it does to inserting the individual tag values into your db?

Comment: Yeah I guess it does then. Not so much a cloud creating isue but inserting the separate tags.

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this question:

[T-SQL Tag Database Architecture Design?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621131/t-sql-tag-database-architecture-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have used the Split() method you will have an array of strings. Iterate over the array using as foreach loop inserting each word in a separate query.